# Bootstrap file input not displaying file name for dynamicaly added file inputs

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, file

I am using bootstrap file input. Its not showing browsed files name for dynamically added file inputs. This is code,

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
        <div class="fileinputs">
            <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
                        Browse&hellip; <input type="file" multiple>
                    </span>
                </span>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
            </div><br/>
        </div>
        <a href="#" id="new-btn">Add New</a>
        <div id="new-div"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.btn-file {


 position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.btn-file input[type=file] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: right;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  opacity: 0;
  background: red;
  cursor: inherit;
  display: block;
}
input[readonly] {
  background-color: white !important;
  cursor: text !important;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#new-btn').on('click', function(){
        $('#new-div').append($('.fileinputs').html());
    });

    $('.btn-file :file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

        var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
        log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

        if( input.length ) {
            input.val(log);
        } else {
            if( log ) alert(log);
        }

    });
});

$(document).on('change', '.btn-file :file', function() {
      var input = $(this),
          numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
          label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
      input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });
```

By using this code I can see the file name only on the first file field. For dynamically added file inputs its not working.

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinodvt22/nehdv4km/). How can I show the browsed file names on corresponding locations ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a delegated event handler to catch your `fileselect` event as the new file inputs are dynamically appended to the DOM after page load, where the original handler is attached. Try this:

```
$(document).on('fileselect', '.btn-file :file', function(event, numFiles, label) {
    // your code...
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/nehdv4km/1/)